# How to handle image datatype through LINQ

Tags: linq, large-data

I tried searching Google and this site for this, but it was hard to find the correct so this may ahve already been asked and answered somewhere, but I couldn't find it.

Anyway, I inherited some code for storing documents in a SQL 2005 database using the image datatype to hold the documents. We have a LINQ method that queries the table returning all of the columns including the document column potentially making this a very expensive operation, especially since we never use the document column on the client side when using this method.

Here's a snippet of the current code:

```
            rtnList = (from c in pdc.View_ActiveDocumentRepositories
                   select new Document(c.ItemId, c.DocumentId, c.Extentsion, c.Filename, c.Document.ToArray(),
            c.ModifiedDate, c.ModifiedBy, dSvc.GetStatus(c.Status), c.ApprovedDate, c.ApprovedBy,
            c.Active)).ToList();
```

In order to reduce the load of this method I'd like to ignore the Document column. I can see a few methods:

1. Remove the reference to the Document column (will this work or will the data be returned through the ActiveDocumentRepositories object even though it's not used)?
2. Create a new view to use that excludes the Document column.
3. Stored procedure that excludes the Document column. (Should be the same as #2, though.)

Any thoughts as to the best answer? Thanks.

Comment: You don't say how your Linq classes are generated, but check out http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/29/linq-to-sql-part-2-defining-our-data-model-classes.aspx where he talks about Delay/Lazy Loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pdc.View_ActiveDocumentRepositories` returns `IQueryable` removing the Document from the `select new` should remove it from the generated select clause.

(I say 'should' because obviously I can't see what's going on in the repository).

Drawback of this approach is that you have to think of leaving out the BLOB every time you query against this repository. We could start a long discussion on exposing IQueryable by repositories, but in short, I would let your repository have a dedicated method for retrieving 'lightweight' document objects.

Comment: +1: LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities will both omit the `Document` from the SQL query they produce if you don't include it in the final projection being evaluated. You easily can see the SQL queries that get produced using LINQPad.

Comment: I ended up creating a new view that excluded the Document column just to make sure. Thanks for the help.